# Mac Custom NSSlider how to override tick mark drawing outside slider frame

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsslider

I'm creating a custom NSSlider where I want to draw labels underneath each of the tick marks.
I'm currently doing this in the custom `NSSliderCell` `-(NSRect)rectOfTickMarkAtIndex` however because the height of `NSSlider` is fixed, the label I'm drawing underneath is being cropped.

Anyone have any ideas?
Also any resources with full implementations of custom NSSliders would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the frame and bounds of the `NSSlider` (which is really a subclass of `NSView`) so it is higher. Then your drawing should work fine. Stick this code in `awakeFromNib`: (Replace `slider` with `self` if you're in its subclass.)

```
NSRect frameRect = [slider frame];
frameRect.size.height = 30;
[slider setFrame:frameRect];
NSRect boundsRect = [slider bounds];
boundsRect.size.height = 30;
[slider setBounds:boundsRect];
```